# Auto indent HTML / Javascript in Notepad++

Tags: javascript, html, notepad++, auto-indent

So it seems this issue has been raised before, a couple of years ago but none of the responses seemed to work on the newest version of Notepad++ 6.2.2

I've also tried using the NppAutoIndent plugin to no avail.

Comment: There are some online tools to auto-indent HTML code, http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier, http://ctrlq.org/beautifier/

Comment: Really though, you want it built into your editor when developing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Notepad# plugin just go to settings then click preferences then click misc then disable Clickable link settings to get rid of crash on scroll hope that helps.

Here is the plugin info if you need it

General plugin (proper new line handling, comments, indenting etc)

Implemented so far:

- Proper new line inside CommentDo//DocBlock for C, C++, Javascript, PHP
- Proper new line for # comment in Ruby
- Indent after opening curly brace for C-like languages, CSS
  and proper indenting for closing curly brace
- Delete current line keeping the column
- Undo closed tab
- Switching tabs with ALT + LEFT/RIGHT
- Wrap selection with Open/Close tag
- Url encode/decode selection
- Autoclose embeded script tags for ruby and php (<% |

  Column ruler

  Indent after opened tag - XML, HTML and PHP

  Close last open tag

  Autonumbering inside CommentDoc/DocBlock and # comment

  Indent after instruction for Ruby - module|class|def|do|if|else|elsif|private

  Match "end" indentation for Ruby

  Autocomplete CommentDoc/DocBlock keywords

  Peek CSS hex colors

  Scroll past end of file

  Convert leading TABS to Spaces and reverse

  Paste indented

  Double click edit tag
  Author: jvdanilo
  Source: https://github.com/jvdanilo/NotepadSharp
  Homepage: https://github.com/jvdanilo/NotepadSharp

Comment: @Barney if you like the answer then please share the wealth and chose as best answer if it does not work then please explain why so I can help.

Answer (score 4):

For javascript, you can try JsMin (JsTool) plugin. It has jsformatter function.